# Using Dapper with HanaDb

Tags: dapper, hana

I'm writing a new library so that our in-house projects can connect to various SAP Business One databases. For a while we've been using PetaPoco which can be configured to handle HanaDb quite nicely, but I've been looking at Dapper as a newer, potentially simpler ORM. The problem is that I don't know how to configure it to HanaDB.

In our code, it's possible to use the same SQL queries on both Microsoft SQL targets and HanaDB targets provided that we use double quotes to delimit all fields. This is possible because PetaPoco can be configured such that a parameter reference such as '@CardCode' in our query works on HANA, we can configure HANA's colon character in the provider.

Using PetaPoco it's also possible to add a custom mapping to deal with HANA's peculiar `HanaDecimal` type.

I'm wondering whether anybody knows whether it's possible to configure Dapper in a similar way i.e.

1. Add a data type mapping to handle data that comes into the c# world as a `HanaDecimal`
2. Internally convert @Parameter in the query to :Parameter so that we can always use the @ prefixed version in our queries.

I have seen some code suggesting that Dapper.Contrib can change the prefix, but I'm not using that - it also sounds as though the setting is across all connections in the process (not just HANA connections) and only allows use of the colon prefix, it doesn't hide the use of the colon prefix, so it may not be what I'm looking for.

It may be the case that I can only use Dapper on SQL only projects, but I'm hopeful that I can get this to work for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Update: I tried adding an SQLMapper.TypeHandler, but it's not quite the solution I'm after. TypeHandle handles the situation where the Poco has a specific non-intrinsic type, such as a Role class, but with HanaDb, the actual DB connector reads Decimal Columns as a `HanaDecimal` type. The `HanaDecimal` type would actually need to map to a 'decimal' in the Poco.

I can map `HanaDecimal` to 'decimal' by using a `SqlMapper.TypeHandler<decimal>`, but theoretically I could specify my target property as decimal, or double, float or even int, long, uint, ulong etc. So I'd have to write a whole raft of mappers.

Does Dapper instead have a kind of mapper that get's triggered based on the incoming object type instead of the target type on the POCO? Or even better a mechanism that triggers on the incoming but also states the target type (which is what PetaPoco has).

For now, it seems that I'd have to write custom mappers for a whole raft of numeric types - buy wouldn't this slow down the whole thing?

Mark

Comment: With Dapper you write your own SQL, so it should handle it.

Comment: Re the parameter: with Dapper you would typically write the native SQL, so you'd use `:Parameter` - Dapper should handle that, since colon parameters are not uncommon; re the HanaDecimal: see `TypeHandler<T>`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding these classes (below) that are registered via SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler - it's the only way that I can think to do. If anybody has a better solution, then let me know - cheers.

```
public class HanaDecimalToDecimalTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<decimal>
{
    public override decimal Parse(object value)
    {
        return (value as HanaDecimal?) != null ? ((HanaDecimal)value).ToDecimal() : Convert.ToDecimal(value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, decimal value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }
}

public class HanaDecimalToDoubleTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<double>
{
    public override double Parse(object value)
    {
        return (value as HanaDecimal?) != null ? (double)((HanaDecimal)value).ToDecimal() : Convert.ToDouble(value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, double value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }
}

public class HanaDecimalToLongTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<long>
{
    public override long Parse(object value)
    {
        return (value as HanaDecimal?) != null ? (long)((HanaDecimal)value).ToDecimal() : Convert.ToInt64(value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, long value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }
}

public class HanaDecimalToIntTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<int>
{
    public override int Parse(object value)
    {
        return (value as HanaDecimal?) != null ? (int)((HanaDecimal)value).ToDecimal() : Convert.ToInt32(value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, int value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }
}
```